# Concatenate percentages in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the Excel Concatenate function. Excel Version : 2013

My End result should be : **Average 40% Red Clauses/Tasks**
But I am getting Average 0.4 Red Clauses/Tasks. So I dont want the 0.4 instead of 40% showing up here.

[image: Excel Version : 2013]

Comment: No Qiu. That did not work.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways this can be solved, but the most straightforward solution would probably be to convert the percentage to a string with the `TEXT` function.

I.e.: Replace C1 in your formula with

```
=TEXT(C1,"###%")
```

Answer (score 0):

What Qiu pointed is almost that. The replacement for C1 should be simply `TEXT(C1;"###%")`. (With no `=`, and using `;` instead of `,`. )